# ʃ pronounced with tongue

Tags: ipa, pronunciation, fricatives

Some people pronounce their [ʃ] not in the 'classic' way but by curving the tongue and bringing it forward toward the upper set of teeth.
[Here's an audio example I've created](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sh_by_tongue.ogg).

My question: is there a known IPA symbol for this, and are there any languages that use this pronunciation?

EDIT: [here's a video](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sh_sound_with_tongue.mpg) depicting the pronunciation.

Comment: what do you mean by the classic way? This sounds like a perfectly normal /ʃ/ to me

Comment: In the given pronunciation, my teeth are quite far apart from one another.
It is the tongue that makes the fricative sound.

Comment: Sounds like somewhere in between of ʃ and [ɕ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_fricative).

Comment: What do you mean by “curving the tongue”? Which part of the tongue, and which way? The tongue is ‘curved’ in the standard, alveolar pronunciation of [ʃ] as well, after all.

Comment: @gil_mo the fricative sound in a /ʃ/ is by definition already made with the tongue, not the teeth

Comment: I guess I'll have to add a video... will soon.

Comment: a diagram of the tongue position in the mouth in both cases would probably be more helpful actually

Comment: I've added a video to the question.

Comment: which pronunciation is the video showing?

Comment: The one I'm referring to in the question.

Comment: Any replies after I've uploaded the video?

Answer (score 3):

Your sample is squarely in the range of IPA [ʃ], and not [ʂ], [ɕ] or [ç]. It sounds perfectly normal to me. [This](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html) is the best place to get standard reference values for IPA letters. If you have samples that are distinct in some way, e.g. one speaker has pronunciation 1 and another has pronunciation 2, you can use IPA diacritics to "nudge" the phonetic values in some manner. For instance you could use the apical vs. laminal diacritics to distinguish two sub-types of [ʃ], if that is indeed what is going on. Bear in mind that people often "intuit" falsehoods about their articulation, so you ought to get objective evidence about articulatory state before making a claim about something that you can't actually inspect.

Comment: I've added a video to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're still producing the same sound, just with a different tongue placement. I hear the difference, I do, but it's still /ʃ/.

If this is for a writing project, something to do with your education (self-edification or formal), or something else you'll have to explain the distinctive tongue placement for the /ʃ/.

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, I'm asking out of sheer curiosity. Funny, but I hear a very different sound .

Comment: Curiousity is wonderful. I'm uncertain what sound you must be hearing. The only other sound I can think that this would approximate would be the voiceless alveolar lateral fricative /ɬ/.

Is that your voice in the video or an audio layover?

Comment: Well, it is not /ɬ/, and yes, it is my voice in the video. My intention was to show how this sound was produced, I guess it is still not clear in the video...

Comment: I wish I could help more, but I'm like the rest. All I hear is /ʃ/. Sorry I couldn't do more.